# render emoji on desktop browser correctly

Tags: php, unicode, mustache, emoji, hogan.js

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxevu6rz/

when I get data from client mobile app posted , and render within desktop browser the `a` tag overlap emoji if previous is rabbit icon, why? and how to solve it?
I tried add css to `a` inline or inline-block but still not work

and another question there is some emoji (next to the girl icon) not showing correctly, how to solve it?
correct one
[image: correct]

```html
<h1>text! ⛷⛷ <a href="/" target="_blank">#tag</a> <a href="/" target="_blank">#tag</a> <a href="/" target="_blank">@user</a></h1>
```

Comment: Which browser(s)? Which operating system(s)? What are you expecting it to look like? Does the font you're using support the character(s)?

Comment: I test on safari. and just test on chrome, can't see any emoji in fiddle, only firefox  shows correct result. I didn't set up `font-style`, browser default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires very up-to-date Unicode support on the browsers of your visitors.

is actually two characters, the man with the OK gesture , and a skin color modifier . Many systems don't support skin colors yet and will show the second character as a colored square or a missing glyph.

And that skier: ⛷, this may just be a problem of missing glyphs on some systems.

This depends on the operating system and the installed fonts. On Windows 10 all emoji show up as expected. On Android (even the latest 6.0) the skin color patch will show up as a missing glyph.

If you want to be sure your visitors actually see emoji, you can use a web font containing these emoji. You'll find a few if you search the web.

Comment: Thanks for reply. `you can use a web font containing these emoji` , the text is from user input on mobile( ios, android and windows),  then store in database. I only can get them with api.  Did you suggest I should find a font containing all emoji icon then just use in css with desktop version?

Comment: @user1575921 Yes you add a web font containing most emoji to the font-family used to display that text. Where that text is coming from is not relevant for rendering it in a browser.